# How to get additional at-will powers

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm currently playing a Deva Wizard in a D&D 4th campaign, and I often found that I would like to have more options for my at-will powers. I know I could have made a Human, but I didn't.

Is there any way to have more at-will power(s) at some point, or am I "stuck" with only 2 ?

Comment: Yes, my bad, this has been corrected.

Comment: The duplicate gives the answer.

Comment: Convince your GM to let you "retrain" your race to Human or Half-elf? :) More seriously, is there a reason you feel you need to have 3 At-Wills? As a Wizard, you're already getting extra powers you can swap between during an extended rest.